# ccTouchesEnded function calling itself again and again even on single touch.

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene with three layers and on the top most layer touch is enabled. On touching that layer once, the ccTouchesEnded is called multiple times (almost 15 times). I can't track the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is: are you sure this layer is only added once? If instances of that layer class have been added 15 times, it would explain the issue you see. Set a breakpoint where you add that particular layer to see if it happens to be added multiple times.